# need a web-player to integrate with php

Tags: php, javascript, web-applications, web

Is there any webplayer that supports dynamic watermark generation and display at random positions that can be integrate with php..? my aim is streaming of video in website securely..

keep one thing in mind while suggesting answers,
Watermarking is not just for a branding purpose, but a Security feature, generate userid as watermark and show at random positions to prevent distribution of copyrighted videos

Thanks in Advance for any help.

Comment: Dont order like this. We are not machines to answer your order. Dont use the "word keep in mind". You have to try something first and then post questions if any difficulties in your task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JWPlayer http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/
It has the facility to integrate with PHP easily.

Comment: can i add watermarks at random positions?

Comment: Yes you can, click here for details; http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/bits-on-the-run/21813/add-watermarks-to-your-content/

Comment: ok. Thanks Moxet Khan for your help. if you find a player that can display watermarks at random positions,please let me know.

Comment: Ok i will let you know..